# How to change the color of a button connected to a via code in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button that is connected to a code. When clicked it begins to do something and when it is clicked again it stops. How can I make it change to green when it is clicked once and change to red when it is clicked again afterwards? please give your suggestions !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the command button or ActiveXcontrol button for the developer tab design, we can use the button shapes to changes the colors by using a simple concept if condition with the below code

```
ActiveSheet.Rectangles.Select
With Selection.ShapeRange`
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.Solid
    .Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = color
End With
```